# Why is that that no matter how many items are in this overflowX'd div, it will only horizontally scroll to the last item but ignore the right padding?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/telestrial-the-scripter/pen/poLdeBe).

Here is code:

HTML

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="page">
    <div class="regular-flow">
    </div>
    <div class="regular-flow">
    </div>
    <div class="regular-flow">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="item">1</div>
      <div class="item">2</div>
      <div class="item">3</div>
      <div class="item">4</div>
      <div class="item">5</div>
      <div class="item">6</div>
      <div class="item">7</div>
      <div class="item">8</div>
      <div class="item">9</div>
      <div class="item">10</div>
      <div class="item">11</div>
      <div class="item">12</div>
      <div class="item">13</div>
      <div class="item">14</div>
      <div class="item">15</div>
      <div class="item">16</div>
    </div>
    <div class="regular-flow">
    </div>
    <div class="regular-flow">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: grey;
}

.page {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.regular-flow {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: limegreen;
  margin: 10px 24px;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  padding-left: 24px;
  padding-right: 24px;
  background-color: orangered;

  display: flex;
  gap: 16px;

  overflow-x: scroll;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-width: none;
}

.container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.item {
  height: 100%;
  width: 121px;
  color: yellow;
  background-color: blue;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

We have several "regular flow" items (green) that keep their own margin consistently down the page (grey). However, I'd like to have a horizontal scrolling div (blue and orangered) that disrespects these boundaries, allowing items to seemingly pass from "edge" to "edge" of the screen. My thought was to `overflowX: 'scroll'` a 100% width div and put padding on the left and right equal to the margin being set by the other items. This way, on the "edges" of the scrollable content, it appears to still respect the margin set by the other regularly flowing items. However, no matter what I try or how many items you put into this container, it will always scroll right only to the right edge of the last item. It will not show the last bit of right padding.

#### Things to keep in mind about the codepen

- You have to have enough items for it to need to scroll horizontally, obviously.
- I am hiding the scrollbar, so hover over the blue/orange container and shift+scrollwheel to move the items. I know this isn't great UX.

#### Most Basic Question

Why can you not scroll right far enough such that the padding-right (orangered) is visible?

### Update

I was able to come up with a workaround for this issue, and that is to go into the parent component (in my codepen, this would be `.container` and remove the padding-right and padding-left at that level, but then add:

```css
.container & .div:first-child {
  padding-left: 24,
}

.container & .div:last-child {
  padding-right: 24,
}
```

This seems to accomplish the same goals, but only if you do NOT have any background color to the `.item`. For my purposes, this works. I only added a background color here for visualizing the issue. I would still be curious if anyone can tell me what the problem above was, so I will keep this question up and not edit the codepen. Thanks!

Comment: what about `.container:after {
    content: "";
    min-width: 24px;
}` ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif This is another approach to solve the problem. I'm not sure that this specifically fills the entire gap, but yeah. This is an approach. I'm really looking more for *why* the codepen scrolling works the way it does.